# How to make and Index with a popupmenu?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I have a few notebooks, say nb1, nb2, nb3, nb4. I would like to make a Index with a popupmenu so that when a clicked in each item,labeled nb1, nb2,..., then the respective notebook open.

I've been  very cheeky trying to create some code, but of course this far from working well. My code is

```
DynamicModule[{var = "nb1.nb", 
  nb1lst = {"nb1.nb", "nb2.nb", "nb3.nb", "nb4.nb"}},
 Column[{
   PopupMenu[
    Dynamic[var], {1 -> "nb1", 2 -> "nb2", 3 -> "nb3", 4 -> "nb4"}],
   PaneSelector[{
     1 -> 
      Dynamic@NotebookOpen[
        FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
          TextString[nb1lst[[var]]]}]],
     2 -> 
      Dynamic@NotebookOpen[
        FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
          TextString[nb1lst[[var]]]}]],
     3 -> 
      Dynamic@NotebookOpen[
        FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
          TextString[nb1lst[[var]]]}]],
     4 -> 
      Dynamic@NotebookOpen[
        FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
          TextString[nb1lst[[var]]]}]]},
    Dynamic[var]]}]
 ]
```

Well, can you help me?

**Edit** I found an easy answer using Kuba suggestion (Action Menu)

**Edit** This answer is  that is that I was looking for

```
Module[{nblist = {"nb1.nb", "nb2.nb", "nb3.nb"}}, 
 ActionMenu["Choose a File...", 
  MapThread[
   RuleDelayed, {nblist, 
    Unevaluated[
       NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], #}]]] & /@ 
     nblist}] ]]
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `var = "nb1.nb"` in the first line to `var = 1`?

Comment: Additionaly, you need `ActionMenu`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend making an index with hyperlinks rather than with approach you are attempting. It is much easier with hyperlinks. I make a hyperlink-based index for all the notebooks that comprise one of my Mathematica projects in that project's master notebook. Here is an example.

[image: index]

Clicking on the grayed notebook file name opens the notebook. Each hyperlink you see in the above image is actually a input/output cell pair with the input cell hidden. Here is the hyperlink with its input cell open.

[image: index_code]

Here the code in a form that you copy and use as a template for creating your own indexes.

```
Hyperlink[
  "TextToolForMSE.nb", 
  {FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "TextToolForMSE.nb"}], None}, 
  BaseStyle -> "Subsubsection",
  ActiveStyle -> GrayLevel[.6]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, an index with hyperlinks is an option, but I am looking for something more small and versatil, like a popup menu, may be with hyperlinks

Answer (score 2):

I've used Kuba suggestion: to use "ActionMenu"  and this works

```
DynamicModule[{nb1lst = {"nb1.nb", "nb2.nb", "nb3.nb"}},
     ActionMenu["LittleIndex",
      {"nb1" :> 
        NotebookOpen[
         FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], TextString[nb1lst[[1]]]}]],
       "nb2" :> 
        NotebookOpen[
         FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], TextString[nb1lst[[2]]]}]],
       "nb3" :> 
        NotebookOpen[
         FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], TextString[nb1lst[[3]]]}]]
       }]
     ]
```